# Возможно ли редактирование файлов .phar в phpstorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Возможно ли редактирование файлов .phar в phpstorm. У меня можно только просмтривать их, можно ли каким нибудь способ их редактировать в самой программе.

Comment: архиватором не открывается?

Comment: каким архиватором?